# Java - Objects comparing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dataset, compare

I have following decision table:

[image: Decision table]

My task is to compare all objects (S1, S2, S3...) with each other using choosen attributes set (e.g {*Distance*, *Capacity*}). So to achieve this I have to create two LOOPS (one nested) and use IF condition.

When objects set is small everything is working fine. But when set is big (e.g 10000 objects) performance of this solution is getting worse...

Is it another, faster, "smarter" way do do it?

Comment: What exactly is your output? Are you sorting?

Comment: You need to tell us more about what the purpose of the whole algorithm is. If you want to compare all objects with each other, there is no better way of doing so than to have nested `for` loops and thus quadratic run time. The question is, do you really need to compare all possible pairs of objects or you need some kind of ordering?

Comment: Example: when attributes set is {Capacity, Requirements} the output could be { {S5, S6}, {S1, S4} }

Sorting: how to perform sporting in this kind of situation?

Comment: Sounds like a case for Comparator and Collections / Arrays.sort

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense to me. Why exactly those objects are selected? Can you show us some code?

Comment: E.g attributes set is {Capacity, Requirements}, so objects {S5, S6} have the same values on Capacity and Requirements attributes... That is why they are choosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pseudocode:**

Step 1. `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();`
 Step 2. For each object s do

```
String key = getSelectedAttributesValueInString();
if (!hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
    hashMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
}
hashMap.get(key).add(s.getName);
```

Here `getSelectedAttributesValueInString` is the concatenation of all the Selected Attributes Value.

For example: object `s1` Attributes `{Distance, Capacity}` the function return `ShortYES`.

Step 3. Now print the hashMap arraylist value that have length greater than 1.

**Complexity Analysis:**

Your approach O(n^2)

My Approach O(n) (Because HashMap add and get complexity is  O(1))